# Angular 2, how to redirect to base of www.example.com when directly accessing www.example.com/otherURL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm certain this has been asked before, but I don't know what information I'm supposed to look for and Angular-specific examples seem a little sparse.

I'm working on a website, using/learning Angular 2 as I go.

Here it is: https://stuart-aitken.tk/

The problem is that if I directly navigate to any of the site's main pages, for example https://stuart-aitken.tk/home, it gives me a 404 error.

When running it in a test environmment from localhost, it works fine.

Not sure what I've done wrong here. When I built the site in the console I specified the base URL like so:

`ng build --prod --base-href="https://stuart-aitken.tk/"`

The RouterModule in app.module.ts looks like this:

`imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'programming', component: ProgrammingComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
  ]`

Also, in index.html I have `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` area.

Is there anything else I should be aware of, or have done wrong?

My first thought at a solution is to just tell my web host provider to redirect all extension URLs to the home page of my website, but I have a feeling this is a very wrong thing to do in the Angular world. But honestly, I just don't know.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Whatever host you are using, you will need to configure it to return the index.html file for any resources that it can't find (since they are resources handled by Angular and not really existing on the web server). https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Ah okay, so my initial thoughts were correct. Great stuff, cheers